# Distribute buttons as evenly as possible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a **variable width** container (a div).

This container contains a **variable** **number** of buttons whose **sizes** **vary**.

```
<div class="buttons">
        <button>Reddit</button>
        <button>G+</button>
        <button>Facebook</button>
        <button>Stack Exchange</button>
        <button>Twitter</button>
        <button>Steam</button>
</div>
```

[See fiddle for HTML and tests](http://jsfiddle.net/kg8nwpyo/).

What I want is to have an harmonious distribution of the buttons whatever the width of the container (assuming it's wider than the widest button).

Right now I have this (if I adjust the window size) :

[image]

What I would want is to have the buttons distributed in the most even way possible (that is the widths of the lines, when there is more than one, as equal as possible). Here that would mean 3 buttons per line :

[image]

but as buttons can be of various sizes the numbers could also be 2-4 for example.

I don't want to stretch the buttons or force their widths, I want to keep the rows centered, and I don't want a JS based answer (I already did it in JS), I want a pure CSS solution. I know it would be [easy in columns](http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) but I don't see a way with rows. It's also possible I missed a recent advance in CSS (I don't care for old browsers and an answer which doesn't work on IE might be acceptable) that's why I'm asking even if it doesn't seem possible right now.

*I've already determined it's not a trivial problem, so don't bother writing an answer saying it's not possible.*

Comment: Will it be responsive?

Comment: @SterlingArcher If you mean does it need to keep adapting if the container is resized, then yes.

Comment: For people interested in the real use case, it's the login page of [Miaou](http://dystroy.org/miaou/), which is dynamically built.

Comment: Can additional tags (span/div between the  buttons) be created or would it be only using the code above?

Comment: @Monty82 If it's reasonable and can be done without computation, yes, but if it involve building a binary tree of the buttons, that would be too much.

Comment: I would accept a valid answer even if it supposes HTML advances and wasn't possible at the time of asking.

Answer (score 4):

As I told you, I think this is not achievable with CSS only (yet) :P

Using some JS, this is the best solution I can think of:

http://jsfiddle.net/1fz0djvL/

```
var buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");

function distribute(){
    buttons.style.width = "auto";
    var height = buttons.offsetHeight;
    do{
        buttons.style.width = buttons.offsetWidth - 1 + "px";
        if(buttons.scrollWidth > buttons.offsetWidth) break;
    }
    while(buttons.offsetHeight == height);
    buttons.style.width = buttons.offsetWidth + 1 + "px";
}
distribute();
window.addEventListener("resize", distribute);
```

It shrinks the container as long it doesn't grow in height.

Comment: I won't accept this answer (*"I don't want a JS based answer"*) but as it's interesting enough I'll give you a +1 as soon as you fix it so that there can't be an infinite loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't contain enough 'math' powers (cross browser) to determine widths and available space.
If they were similarly shaped, it would be easier to accomplish with a grid based system like bootstrap and media queries.   But because 15 'G+' buttons fit in 2 'stackoverflow' space, it will never be the solution you want without determining element widths.

I'd suggest resulting to the JS solution you came up with already.