# How to preserve a spacing template on multiple lines using a flex-box container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Here is where I'm starting: http://jsfiddle.net/Vercingetorix333/7b2L25a5/2/

As you can see The spacing that I have on either end of the container (flex size: 10) is much larger than the spaces between the content (flex size: 2.5). At the moment when a user decreases the size of the html window, the elements do eventually wrap to the second line (as intended).

What I'd like to do however is set the first window resizing break-point / responsiveness factor so that when content does move to the second line (maybe using `@media....` in css?) it takes the two right-most content divs in one go.

Then I desire for *each* line in the container to look like this:

large buffer - **content** - small buffer - **content** - large buffer

Can I do this purely in css? Or do I need some javascript?

Edit: Adding my code from Fiddle (for posterity's sake).

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer_container">

    <div class="outer_buffer"></div>

    <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    <div class="inner_buffer"></div>
    <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    <div class="inner_buffer"></div>
    <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    <div class="inner_buffer"></div>
    <div class="content">Some Content</div>

    <div class="outer_buffer"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.outer_buffer{
    flex-grow: 10;
}
.inner_buffer{
    flex-grow: 2.5;
}
.content{
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: you can't with raw css, need some js! check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290014/distribute-buttons-as-evenly-as-possible/25290399#25290399

Comment: I think you're correct.

Comment: I've been able to create the above desired effect using Javascript. I am looking into Less variables & mixins to see if there's an additional way.

Comment: Pure CSS might be possible. Depends on how much flexibility you need? Can you assume a set number of items? Can you assume a fixed size on the items?

Comment: The relevant code needs to be included in the question.  This question won't be useful to anyone when jsfiddle goes down.

Comment: Resolved: Pure CSS is possible. See Mary's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: previosly here was my example solution based on wrong assumptions about the limitation of items count and their behavior. The jsfiddle example of that solution was http://jsfiddle.net/7b2L25a5/32/, and for JS version - http://jsfiddle.net/7b2L25a5/38/

### EDITED SOLUTION

The desired behavior can be achieved by adding one extra wrapper (instead of several 'buffer' divs) and changing the `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` values of the inner wrapper depending on the number of items that fit to one line, so the spaces between items stretch with the constant proportion to the outer 'buffers' (for which the pseudo elements of the outer container are used):

```css
body { margin: 10px 0; }

.outer_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

.outer_container::before,
.outer_container::after {
    content: '';
    flex: 4 0 0;
}

.middle_container {    
    display: flex;
    /* if there are 2 items on each line,
       we need to stretch 1 space */
    flex: 1 0 104px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.content{
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 260px) {
    /* if there are 4 items on each line,
       we need to stretch 3 spaces */
    .middle_container { flex: 3 0 208px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
    <div class="middle_container">
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The number of needed media queries depends on the number of layout variations. For two variations (2 or 4 items per line) only one MQ is needed.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to post. The trouble with your solution is that it doesn't move two elements at the same time to the subsequent line. If you check out Mary's above Fiddle, you'll see the desired behavior in action.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that requirement. In fact, it can be fixed with minimal modification, you will even need less keypoints for media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/7b2L25a5/39/

Comment: And the solution for your initial 4 items, in fact, needs just one media query and still zero buffer divs: http://jsfiddle.net/7b2L25a5/40/

Comment: Thank you. This seems like an efficient way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this answer. I'm using two sets of large (flex-grow 10) and small (flex-grow 2.5) buffer `div`s for first and second window resizing break-points and I've systematically assigned `display: none` to one set at a time to show only one set of large and small buffer `div`s for each `@media` query break-point. I'm using two container `div`s and each container `div` have two content `div`s and at the first window resizing `@media` query break-point moves the right container to the second line. Actually, it takes the two right-most content `div`s in one go as per your desire result.

Please look at my answer's edited section (below) to accomplish it with minimum HTML markup by using the CSS pseudo-elements (i.e. `:after` and `:before`).

#### Result:

> At first @media query break-point the result look like this:
>
> large buffer (10) - **content** - small buffer (2.5) - **content** -
>   large buffer (10)
>  large buffer (10) - **content** - small buffer
>   (2.5) - **content** - large buffer (10)

All you need to do is calculate the `max-width` of CSS `@media` queries break points as per `.content` size for this solution.

**For Example:** If you set the `width` of `.content` to `200px` then:

> 1st @media query break point of max-width is: **4 x 200px = 800px**
>
> 2nd @media query break point of max-width is: **2 x 200px = 400px**
>
> **Example: JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0u4eLqa3/)**

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cdxms846/)

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 2.5;
}
.content {
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.lg {
    flex-grow: 10;
}
.sm {
    flex-grow: 2.5;
}
.w-buffer {
    display: block;
}
.c-buffer {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 224px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: block;
    }
    .container {
        justify-content: center;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }
    .w-buffer {
        display: none;
    }
    .c-buffer {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 120px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }
    .w-buffer, .c-buffer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="w-buffer lg"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c-buffer lg"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="c-buffer sm"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="c-buffer lg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-buffer sm"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c-buffer lg"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="c-buffer sm"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="c-buffer lg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-buffer lg"></div>
</div>
```

You could also use the CSS [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) (i.e. `:after` and `:before`) to reduce the number of buffer `div`s.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjn1nbwz/)

```css
body {
    margin: 8px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 2.5;
}
.content {
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.pseudo-buffer:before, .pseudo-buffer:after {
    content:" ";
    display: block;
}
.wrapper.pseudo-buffer:before, .wrapper.pseudo-buffer:after {
    flex-grow: 10;
}
.buffer {
    flex-grow: 2.5;
}
@media (max-width: 224px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: block;
    }
    .container {
        justify-content: center;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }
    .wrapper.pseudo-buffer:before, .wrapper.pseudo-buffer:after {
        display: none;
    }
    .container.pseudo-buffer:before, .container.pseudo-buffer:after {
        flex-grow: 10;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 120px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }
    .wrapper.pseudo-buffer:before, .wrapper.pseudo-buffer:after, .container.pseudo-buffer:before, .container.pseudo-buffer:after, .buffer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper pseudo-buffer">
    <div class="container pseudo-buffer">
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="buffer"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="buffer"></div>
    <div class="container pseudo-buffer">
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="buffer"></div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [EDITED]

You could also do it without using any `buffer` divs just by set the width to `container` as per `@media` queries break-point and I'm using two `@media` queries break-point because I think, if there is only one `content` div per line then `content` divs should be horizontally center inside the `container` div and If you don't want to use the second `@media` query break-point then just remove it and set `min-width: 104px;` to the `container` for `@media (max-width: 208px)`. You could do it like this **[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/10arkg8h/)**

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pgntfcpn/)

```css
body {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.content {
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 7.5; /* Total space between 4 content divs same as 3 x 2.5 flex-grow */
}
.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
    content: " ";
    flex-grow: 10;
}
@media (max-width: 208px) {
    .container {
        width: 104px; /* 2 (content divs per line) x 52px (content div's width) */
        flex-grow: 2.5;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 104px) {
    .container {
        width: 52px;
        flex-grow: 0; /* Set value 0 to center content divs inside the container */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
        <div class="content">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer without using any javascript. Thank you as well for adding the more efficient pseudo-element version. Both of them work perfectly.

Comment: @Vercingetorix I've updated my answer with the more efficient method without using any `buffer` divs and I've also explained the reason why I'm using two `@media` queries break-point. Please look at the new edited section again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understand why do you need buffer divs. All you need to do is right CSS styling of top component, than you can remove the buffers.

```
.outer_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b2L25a5/29/)

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab. Your Fiddle doesn't accomplish the result I've stated in my question however. At the break point where the four content elements can no longer fit into one row, your code sends a single content element to the subsequent row beneath the first three. I want 'two' elements to go at the same time while preserving the spacing scheme I specified above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely in CSS. 
First, as you said.. yes you need @media type, using a external CSS file.

In your CSS file, it may look like this:

```
@media all { 
    .class  
    #id
}
```

the @media all header is for all other screens, other than the ones you specify. It is like a base set. For specific ones, see the format below:

```
@media screen @media screen and (min-width: 1278px) and (max-width: 1282px) {
#id
.class
}
```

Adding ids and classes between the two parenthesis above, will specify special rules that will overwrite the rules written in @media all header and would come into effect only on the screen whose width is between 1278px to 1282px, so as you can see we are here targeting a screen of 1280px x XXX height {12 inch typical low-end netbook}

The trick to your question is the meta structure however. Lets suppose we have 4 pictures of 400px square. Giving a total width of 400+400+400+400=1600px. So on a 800px width screen, only two pictures would be shown in line 1, and remaining 2 on the second line.

If yo were to apply flex-box without proper html markup, you might end up with a transition, where only the right most item moves to the second line.

From what I understand from your question, that you want the transition however to be 2 items moving to second line like best buddies. Something like this:

becomes

The correct Markup would something like this:

```
<div id="Container">

<div id="Inner"> <div id="Box">Content1</div> <div id="Box">Content2</div> </div>
<div id="Inner"> <div id="Box">Content3</div> <div id="Box">Content4</div> </div>

</div>
```

and the correct CSS is:

```
#Container { position: relative; width: auto; min-width: 800px; display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; } 

#Inner { position: relative; display: inline-block; }

#Box { position: relative; display: block; }
```

The flex container is something new with HTML5, so I have personally experienced some glitches. You might have to change the position of #Box to 'static' instead of 'relative', and writing nothing might not work either (in which case it should default back to static, but I have seen instances where it doesn't.

I'm very sure that what I have written above is what you need. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. And you are correct that it is possible. The first post took my existing Fiddle and actually made it work in two different ways.